# Prove that if an odd prime p divides an integer of the form $x^2 + 3y^2$, then $p$ is also of the form $x^2 + 3y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is from *Primes of the form x^2 + ny^2* by Cox.

The exercise in the book goes on to say:

> The argument is more complicated because the descent step fails for $p=2$. Thus, if it fails for some odd prime $p$, you have to produce an odd prime $q < p$ where it also fails.

The descent step they're referring to is Euler's proof by descent of Fermat's sum of squares theorem.

I honestly think I'm struggling to even understand the question. Especially the line

> the descent step fails for $p=2$.

How could $p=2$ if we're trying to prove a property of odd primes $p$? And furthermore, how could $p=2$ ever be of the form $x^2 + 3y^2$? What integers $x$ and $y$ would make that true?

Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Every prime $p$ divides an integer of the form $x^2+3y^2$, as you can see by taking $x=y=p$.

Comment: @WillO right, the prompt though is to prove that **if** a prime $p$ divides another integer of the form $x^2 + 3y^2$, then that prime $p$ can also be written in the form $x^2 + 3y^2$.

Comment: So you're trying to prove that every odd prime is of the form $x^2+3y^2$.  What about $p=5$?

Comment: Every odd prime that divides some integer of the form $x^2 + 3y^2$. Notice "of the form" - the x's and y's would probably be different.  $p=5$ cannot be written in that form and thus does not divide any integer that can, at least according to this prompt.

Comment: So 5 does not divide 100?

Comment: Can you write 100 in the form $x^2 + 3y^2$? $x$ and $y$ have to be coprime, by the way. So $x=y=5$ wouldn't work. Should have mentioned that earlier, sorry.

Comment: Yes. as I've already shown you in my first comment.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ must be coprime. See my edit. Sorry.

Comment: For more information and Euler's proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Euler's_proof_by_infinite_descent

Comment: What I don't understand is when they say "the descent step fails for $p=2$". If someone were able to point out where specifically it fails, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

@HoldenNelson. You are right to be puzzled by the comment about the prime $2$.

What happens in the descent step is that one has the equation $$x^2+3y^2=Np$$ where, by the standard argument, we can assume that $N<p$. Furthermore, we can say that any odd prime dividing $N$ is necessarily of the form $a^2+3b^2$. However, we cannot then immediately say that $N$ is of the form $a^2+3b^2$ because it might contain a factor of $2$ as well as odd primes.

This is what the book is referring to but saying "$p=2$" was a very misleading use of the letter "$p$" which had already been allocated to a specific odd prime.